Is it possible to have non-matching symbols for different BOM variants in OrCAD CIS?
Is it possible to create BOM variants in OrCAD CIS that would have different components (for example a resistor instead of a capacitor) at the same positions?
Here is the scenario: Say we have some subcircuit A in a schematic, which is required by a certification agency (UL). When certifying for other locales that don't require UL we don't need to populate any of the subcircuit components, but the output of the subcircuit A should be pulled down.
We have no provision for the resistor there, but there is a filter cap that goes to the ground, so naturally the easy solution would be to take the same 0402 size resistor and place it instead of the capacitor.
These kind of workarounds worked well so far for us until we switched to the CIS. OrCAD does not like the idea of making a BOM variant that has a resistor in place of the capacitor (which is in the core design).
I thought of having a double footprint (both 0402 for the resistor and the capacitor), but this solution can't be used right now; we'd need to re-release the PCB to the manufacturer, which is not a fast process.
We could make some kind of dummy component that could either a resistor or a capacitor, but this would probably create more confusion in the long term and clutter the project.
Any ideas what can be done here?

To whoever downvotes this: could you please explain why so that I can improve it?
